# Regular Expression how to match properties where the value can be of type xml

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to fix one regular expression that's not working correctly.

as it is now: `<[^>]*(>|$)`

that regular expression works when the string is the following:

```
<?UMBRACO_MACRO  macroalias="RelatedLinks"  PushCollection="Test123"  />
```

but I need it to also match this:

```
<?UMBRACO_MACRO  macroalias="RelatedLinksPresentation"  PushCollection="<links><link title="test" link="1058" type="internal" newwindow="1" /></links>"  />
```

where the content of one property is in xml.

that xml value produces 3 groups...

Edit:

the code looks like this:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);


        ...........            

        Regex tagregex = new Regex("<[^>]*(>|$)", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        MatchCollection tags = tagregex.Matches(_data.Value.ToString());

        List<int> editornumbers = new List<int>();
        string sortorder = string.Empty;


        for (int i = 0; i < _maxNumber; i++)
        {
            if (!editornumbers.Contains(i))
            {
                string data = string.Empty;

                if (tags.Count > i)
                    data = tags[i].Value;

                MacroEditor macroEditor = new MacroEditor(data, _allowedMacros);
                macroEditor.ID = ID + "macroeditor_" + i;

                this.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(macroEditor);
            }
        }

        this.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));

        if (tags.Count == _maxNumber)
        {
            _addMacro.Enabled = false;
            _limit.Visible = true;
        }

        MacroContainerEvent.Execute += new MacroContainerEvent.ExecuteHandler(MacroContainerEvent_Execute);

    }
```

I know why they made it that way; they need to parse it as the value comes from the database and it may have multiple strings like that, for example

```
<?UMBRACO_MACRO  macroalias="RelatedLinks"  PushCollection="Test123"  />
<?UMBRACO_MACRO  macroalias="RelatedLinks"  PushCollection="<links><link title="test" link="1058" type="internal" newwindow="1" /></links>"  />
<?UMBRACO_MACRO  macroalias="RelatedLinks"  PushCollection="Test123"  />
<?UMBRACO_MACRO  macroalias="RelatedLinks"  PushCollection="Test123"  />
```

that's 4 macros and the regular expression is made to split them into separate instances.

And to be clear this is not an xml, it's a pattern where the framework Umbraco takes out values from their properties. This time it happens to be xml in the value and the regular expression that needs to separate the UMBRACO_MACRO strings freaked out.

Edit:
The question now is how do I ignore everything between "" <-- I don't even want the regex to care whats inside the value field, is that possible ?

I found this too hard to do but I found another road to walk on :D I now HtmlEncode the value before it's saved and then when I get it I decode, then it works.

Comment: The regular expression *is*  working properly. But using regular expressions to match XML is a futile task. Use a parser instead. On second thought, what you posted there doesn't even appear to be valid XML, so I'm not sure what your options are...

Comment: Xml embedded in Xml.  For whatever problem you're trying to solve, that's probably the wrong solution.

Comment: Are the strings you showed a substring of another larger string, or are they complete strings?  I.E. if all you want to match is a string that starts with a < and ends with a >, then that can be done. Otherwise, as other commenters have said, you are out of luck.

Comment: yea well it will alway start with <? and end with /> and in between there it will be stuff like propertyNmae="somevalue" etc so the pattern will alway be that if somehow i can build onto that expression so it ignores the value in between "" ?

Comment: I believe your 2nd example is invalid, as you cannot have `param="some"text"here"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment and on Ωmega's:

Your data structure which is plainly invalid makes this task impossible. You say that you want to ignore text between quotes. Which is fine in principle (and very well possible with regular expressions), however in your case, the quoted text contains unescaped quotes. This leads to the problematic situation that whatever *is*  actually quoted in your embedded string will be *outside* of double quotes! To illustrate this point, this is your string split into unquoted and quoted parts:

```
<?UMBRACO_MACRO  macroalias=
"RelatedLinks"
PushCollection=
"<links><link title="
test
" link="
1058
" type="
internal
" newwindow="
1
" /></links>"
/>
```

Your source data should be at least escaping the inner quotes, like this:

```
<?UMBRACO_MACRO  macroalias="RelatedLinks"  PushCollection="<links><link title=\"test\" link=\"1058\" type=\"internal\" newwindow=\"1\" /></links>"  />
```

As long as you don't fix that, it's going to be impossible to parse.

To be able to use an XML parser (which would otherwise be perfect for this task), you'd need `&quot;` character entities instead of `\"`.

So, if you correctly escape your source string like this (line breaks added for clarity):

```
<?UMBRACO_MACRO  macroalias="RelatedLinks"  
  PushCollection="&lt;links&gt;
  &lt;link title=&quot;test&quot; 
  link=&quot;1058&quot; 
  type=&quot;internal&quot; 
  newwindow=&quot;1&quot;
  /&gt;
  &lt;/links&gt;"  
/>
```

then you could use your original regex.

Comment: Ok i dident know that, question can i load that xml with the escaped stuff into an xmldocument or do i need to remove the escaped before i do that ? to escape them is not a problem i can add that. then if i had that format how would i build the regular expression to ignore stuff inside "" ?

Comment: Thancks for the help i will chance the structure of the datatype to what you have suggested. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and plug it into http://txt2re.com/index-csharp.php3 and take it from there